# Append the values in a key (without adding one more dictionary)-Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and I want to add more values to a key.

```
 dict_1={"one":1,"two":2,"three and four":3}
```

so I want to append the key `three and four` from `3` to `3,4`
what I have done is-

```
dict_1["three and four"].append(4)
```

but this doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to append to the *value* of the dict?  Because that's what your code looks like you're trying to do.  You really shouldn't try to change the keys.  That causes havoc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't append to a number.  If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you need to do this:

```
dict_l = { "one" : [1], "two" : [2], "three and four": [3] }
dict_l["three and four"].append(4)
```

Now, your values are `list`s, so you can append.

After running, your `dict_l` will look like this:

```
{'three and four': [3, 4], 'two': [2], 'one': [1]}
```

Comment: Or maybe something like this: dict_l = { "one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three and four": [3, 4] }

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but I find things are usually easier to work with if your values are of a consistent type.

Comment: Thanks @IanMcLaird Actually I have made a GUI and I want to serializes the values of the dictionary to the entry widgets of my GUI. So, now my GUI has a "add button" that adds more rows and I want  that as I enter the value to the widget my key of dictionary should append and store the value. Upon de-serializing, it should insert the values back in

Comment: This actually is doing nothing. It appends the value and then both value store in the same entry widget `['2','3']` that doesn't help.

Comment: I don't really follow you.  Perhaps you should ask another question, and clearly explain what you're trying to do, and what you're seeing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be changing the type of value stored - right now it's just an int. So you'd have to get whatever's in there now, and if it's not a list, start a new one, then append the 4:

```
dict_1['three and four'] = [].append(dict_1['three and four'])
dict_1['three and four'].append(4)
```

Comment: `[].append(dict_1['three and four'])` => returns `None`

Comment: Yes, you mean `dict_l['three and four'] = [dict_l['three and four']]`

Comment: @IanMcLaird although that'd give you a list in a list if it's already a list :\

Answer (score -1):

You can't append a value to a dict key, but you can replace the value:

```
dict_1["three and four"] = 4
```